# Incompatible Types at indexOf()

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program in Java, but there appears to be an error. At **hexnumber.indexOf(tempstring)**, it gave me the error message "incompatible types". I'm confused by this because I clearly defined tempstring to be a String object the line before. How should I fix this?

```
String hexnumber = "0123456789ABCDEF";
String hexsolution = "";
int remainder = newDecNumber % 16;
String tempstring = Integer.toString(remainder);
hexsolution.concat(hexnumber.indexOf(tempstring));
newDecNumber = newDecNumber /= 16;
```

Comment: Well, `concat()` takes a `String`, while `indexOf()` returns an `int`.

Comment: Note that you have another bug in your code. `concat` returns the new string, it does NOT modify `hexsolution`. So you have to update the variable.

Comment: Also this statement `newDecNumber = newDecNumber /= 16;` is super weird and does unecessary stuff. Replace it by just `newDecNumber /= 16;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tdranv's comment is correct -- `String.concat()` takes a `String` argument and returns a new String.  It looks like your intent is:

```java
hexsolution = hexsolution.concat(hexnumber.substring(remainder, 1));
```

Comment: For the sake of having a self-contained complete answer, could you add what he said?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
String hexnumber = "0123456789ABCDEF";
String hexsolution = "";
int remainder = newDecNumber % 16;
String tempstring = Integer.toString(remainder);    
hexsolution = hexsolution.concat(hexnumber.substring(remainder, 1));
newDecNumber /= 16;
```

Now, the **concat()** parameter is of String type, so there will be no error with types.

And the **hexsolution** variable is modified properly now, because concat() function does not modify directly the variable.